# Perform foreach loop on table column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, foreach

I need to iterate through a table column and for each value to execute a simple `SELECT` statement.

I get the result table with the following statement:

```
SELECT event_id, count(event_id) as occurence
FROM event
GROUP BY event_id
ORDER BY occurence DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Output:

```
 event_id | occurence
---------------------
 1234567  | 56678
 8901234  | 86753
```

For each event_id from the output table I need to execute a `SELECT` statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE event_id = 'event_id from result row'
```

Expected output:

```
 event_id | even_type | event_time
 ----------------------------
 1234567  | .......   | .......
 1234567  | .......   | .......



 8901234  | .......   | .......
 8901234  | .......   | .......
```

In other words: I need to get the 50 most occuring `event_ids` from the `event` table and then retrieve all available data for those specific events.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM event WHERE event_id in (...)`?

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you expect from that "loop". Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I edited the question. I hope this clarifies my intend.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few way to handle this but here is one way:

```
SELECT  a.*, b.event_type, b.event_time
FROM
(
    SELECT event_id, count(event_id) as occurence
    FROM event
    GROUP BY event_id
    ORDER BY occurence DESC
    LIMIT 50
) a
JOIN event b ON (b.event_id = a.event_id)
;
```

Instead of specific columns from what I called 'b' you could select b.* for all columns.

Answer (score 0):

No need to even join - just simply use a window function! See below:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  
        *, 
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY event_id) AS event_count 
    FROM event 
) A 
ORDER BY event_count DESC
LIMIT 50
```